# How do I get this baseball program to run?

Tags: cobol

I have this cobol program I am trying to write but I can't run it because there are a lot of error (red/blue lines) I believe it has something to do with reading in and out the file. I was thinking the error could be because I didn't put in a FD but when I did, it still error. My seq file is named BASEBALL-2.seq.

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.

   01 LINE-COUNT                   PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  WS-DATE.
       05  RUN-YEAR                PIC XX.
       05  RUN-MONTH               PIC XX.
       05  RUN-DAY                 PIC XX.
   01  HEADING-LINE-1.
       05                          PIC X(24) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(26)
           VALUE 'BASEBALL PLAYER STATISTICS'.
       05                          PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.
       05  HL-1-DATE.
           10  MONTH-2             PIC XX.
           10                      PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  DAY-2               PIC XX.
           10                      PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  YEAR-2              PIC XX.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE SPACES.
       05  PAGE-1                  PIC X(4)   VALUE 'PAGE'.

   01  HEADING-LINE-2.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE 'LEAGUE'.
       05                          PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'TEAM'.
       05                          PIC X(5)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'NAME'.
       05                          PIC X(10)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'HITS'.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(7)   VALUE 'AT BATS'.
   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05 BLANK-A-OUT              PIC X      VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-LEAGUE                PIC XX.
       05 BLANK-B-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-TEAM                  PIC X(3).
       05 BLANK-C-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-NAME                  PIC X(10).
       05 BLANK-D-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-HITS                  PIC ZZ9.
       05 BLANK-E-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-AT-BATS               PIC ZZ9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       OPEN INPUT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       OPEN OUTPUT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT

       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE
       MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-2
       MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-2
       MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-2
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
           READ BASEBALL-FILE-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM

       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
       STOP RUN.


   200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
       MOVE LEAGUE-IN TO DL-LEAGUE
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
       MOVE TEAM-IN TO DL-TEAM
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-B-OUT
       MOVE NAME-IN TO DL-NAME
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-C-OUT
       MOVE HITS-IN TO DL-HITS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-D-OUT
       MOVE AT-BATS-IN TO DL-AT-BATS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-E-OUT
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.

   300-LINE.
       IF  LINE-COUNT >= 50
           PERFORM 400-NEXT-PAGE
       END-IF
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT.

   400-NEXT-PAGE.
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
       MOVE ZEROS TO LINE-COUNT.
```

Comment: What do you mean with "blue and red lines"? I _guess_ that is seen in an editor/ide you are not actually referencing, in this case those are likely errors (red) and hints (blue) [from a COBOL compiler you don't tell us about] which you see when hovering over those.
If you post the actual errors then we should be able to help. Note: as this is no "coding site" but a Q+A one the common type of question is "I get the error XYZ and tried to fix it by ABC but DEF happens" or "How to fix XYZ" - I highly suggest to adjust the question.

Comment: How do you think we should be able to *guess* what errors you got?? Show complete source, show error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only post from your  `WORKING STORAGE` onward. Could you show us how the `FILE SECTION` was written? Also, the errors that you're receiving.

Consider:

- Use `FILLER` instead of blank spaces for fields and variables names.
- Be careful with the flow, you're not calling to `300-LINE` paragraph. `PERFORM` breaks when another paragraph begins.
- That in `200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD` you're not adding the 2 lines to `LINE-COUNT`.

For the rest, I see it perfect.